# Unable to convert full string from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

I have a pandas series where I save strings. But when I wish to convert this series to string, each cell is limited to a number of character. Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong or if theres a workaroud.

```
data = np.array(['good day good sir how are you doing today? I sure hope you are well', 'e', 'e', 'k','s']) 
ser = pd.Series(data) 
ser.to_string()
```

The current output:

```
0    good day good sir how are you doing today? I s...\n1                                                    e\n2                                                    e\n3                                                    k\n4                                                    s'
```

Wanted output:

```
'0 good day good sir how are you doing today? I sure hope you are well\n1 e\n2 e\n3 k\n4 s'
```

Is there any way I can get a full string?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Its the 
'0 good day good sir how are you doing today? I sure hope you are well\n1 e\n2 e\n3 k\n4 s'

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.array(['good day good sir how are you doing today? I sure hope you are well', 'e', 'e', 'k','s']) 
ser = pd.Series(data) 
print('\\n'.join(ser))
```

Comment: change \\n in `''` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**Series.to_string()** returns a string representation of the Series, not a reduced value, if you want to combine all string in a single one, replace  `ser.to_string()` for `" ".join(ser)` and it will concat all string with a space.

Answer (score 0):

I read you `expected output` as a table because u expected the `1` , `2` , `3`

[image: Do you expecting a table like this?]